# New endpoint in my account gives 404 Error Woocommerce 3.6.5 and WP 5.2.2

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

```
function bbloomer_add_premium_support_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'support', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}

add_action( 'init', 'bbloomer_add_premium_support_endpoint' );

// ------------------
// 2. Add new query var

function bbloomer_premium_support_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'support';
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'bbloomer_premium_support_query_vars', 0 );

// 3. Insert the new endpoint into the My Account menu

function bbloomer_add_premium_support_link_my_account( $items ) {
    $items['support'] = 'Premium Support';
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'bbloomer_add_premium_support_link_my_account' );
```

Comment: Have you flushed/re-saved your permalink settings since adding the code?

Comment: It works like charm ...thank you sir...made my day

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you flush/re-save your settings in *Permalinks > Settings* whenever you add code the adds a rewrite endpoint or rule.

Also, the most up to date and optimal way to add an account endpoint in WooCommerce would be to use the `woocommerce_get_query_vars` filter:

```
/**
 * Register support endpoint.
 *
 * @param array $query_vars WooCommerce query vars.
 */
function wpse_343129_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars['support']   = 'support';

    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_query_vars', 'wpse_343129_query_vars' );
```

It saves you having to use 2 separate functions, and ensures that you can use filters like `woocommerce_endpoint_support_title` to properly update the account page title:

```
/**
 * Support account page endpoint title.
 *
 * @param string $title Endpoint title.
 * @param string $endpoint Current endpoint.
 */
function wpse_343129_support_endpoint_title( $title, $endpoint ) {
    return 'Support';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_endpoint_support_title', 'wpse_343129_support_endpoint_title', 10, 2 );
```